# JIRA post functions storage

Tags: workflow, jira

I just upgraded to JIRA 5 and one of my plugins stopped working. It is ok because it is very old. But, I had a post function related to this plugin in many many workflows and delete it manually would drive me nuts. My question is where are post functions stored, in database or somewhere in xml file? Or any idea how to get rid of it?

Thanks

-Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As XML text in the database. They can be modified with SQL commands, with a bit of fiddling. Do it on a staging instance first!

Comment: Thanks, I already found it in database table 'jiraworkflows'. I used only sql command to replace what I needed to.